# Loading a keystore and getting the signature in c#

Tags: c#, jwt, salesforce, keystore

I have some sample code from SalesForce. The code below is written in Java. I am trying to convert it to C# how am unable to find libraries that will do the same for the Keystore.

```
  //Load the private key from a keystore
  KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
  keystore.load(new FileInputStream("./path/to/keystore.jks"), "keystorepassword".toCharArray());
  PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("certalias", "privatekeypassword".toCharArray());

  //Sign the JWT Header + "." + JWT Claims Object
  Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
  signature.initSign(privateKey);
  signature.update(token.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
  String signedPayload = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(signature.sign());
```

My attempt is as follows for the signature:

```
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\temp\TestCert.jks");
    var certParser = new bcrypto.X509CertificateParser();
    var privateCertBouncy = certParser.ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());
    var xx = privateCertBouncy.GetSignature();
    Array.Reverse(xx);
    token.Append(System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(BitConverter.ToString(xx))));
```

Answer (score 0):

JKS is the Java Keystore Format and is not suited for .NET / C#.
I would suggest that you follow the Salesforce documentation:

[Create a Private Key and Self-Signed Digital Certificate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_key_and_cert.htm)

The private key you will get in step 3 is in PEM format and could be processed for instance by: [BouncyCastle C# library](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) like so:

```
public static class KeyHelpers
{

    public static PrivateKeyWrapper CreatePrivateKeyWrapper(string key)
    {
            
        var keyStruct = RsaPrivateKeyStructure
            .GetInstance(
                (Asn1Sequence)Asn1Object
                    .FromByteArray(Convert
                        .FromBase64String(CommonHelpers.RemoveHeaderFooterFromKey(key)))
            );

        return new PrivateKeyWrapper
        {
            Modulus = keyStruct.Modulus, 
            Exponent = keyStruct.PrivateExponent
        };
    }

    public static byte[] CreateSignature(PrivateKeyWrapper privateKeyWrapper, byte[] bytesToSign)
    {
        var sig = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA" + 256 + "withRSA");
        sig.Init(
            true, 
            new RsaKeyParameters(
                true, 
                privateKeyWrapper.Modulus, 
                privateKeyWrapper.Exponent
            )
        );
        sig.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length);

        return sig.GenerateSignature();
    }

    public static PrivateKeyWrapper CreatePrivateKeyWrapperWithPassPhrase(string key, string passphrase)
    {
        var pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(key), new PasswordFinder(passphrase));
        var pem = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair) pemReader.ReadObject();
        var param = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters) pem.Private;

        return new PrivateKeyWrapper
        {
            Modulus = param.Modulus, 
            Exponent = param.Exponent
        };
    }
}
```

Full functional code could be found here: [ForceDotNetJwtCompanion](https://github.com/claboran/ForceDotNetJwtCompanion)